# How to add custom tab page in backend?

Tags: hooks, admin-menu

I would like to learn about create page and tab in admin panel. Please let me know useful hook and filter list.

Comment: You can find many infos about this in the [official codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus). If - after reading & trying out - you have any more questions, feel free to ask them here

Comment: IF you mean tabs in an admin page, like [this examples](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15800) there always static. You can create them via html/php, without a core functions. Also you find the markup, hints in [this plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/wordpress-admin-style), that helps to create backend areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add menu on the WordPress dashboard on the left panel than there are several ways to do that like in the following links

[add_menu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/)

[add_options_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page)

add_menu_page adds a menu to the left panel of wp-admin dashboard whereas add_options_page will add a menu under the settings menu.